# Convert from one POJO to another POJO using MapStruct

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapstruct

I need to convert from One pojo to Other using MapStruct.

```
POJO A : 

String A;
String b;
Map <String, Object> section;

POJO B : 

String D;
String E;
String F;
String J; 
String[] H;
```

for D, E it is a straight map i can do it via Mapping annotation
like :

`@Mapping(source = "a",target = "D")`

now i'm looking for Map conversion to F, J, H (String Array).

Any possible leads will help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to achieve using `expression` keyword

```
@Mapping(target = "F", expression = "java(returnStringValue(map, inputKeyName))")

default String returnStringValue(Map<String, Object> detailsMap, String inputKey) {
     if (detailsMap.containsKey(inputKey)) {
         return detailsMap.get(inputKey).toString();
     }
     return null;
 }
```